# OpenGL and Qt 5.5: glm::perspective doesnt work

Tags: qt, opengl, glm-math

I have made the following perspective matrix to isolate the problem to the glm perspective function:

```
QMatrix4x4 proj (1.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f,
                 0.f, 1.f, 0.f, 0.f,
                 0.f, 0.f, 1.f, 0.0f,
                 0.f, 0.f, 1.1f, 1.f);
```

This works and produces an image. However, when trying to use glm to construct the perspective matrix as so:

```
glm::mat4 proj;
proj = glm::perspective(
            glm::radians(80.0f),
            1.0f,
            0.0f,
            2.0f
       );
```

Nothing comes up.

I was under the impression that when putting `0.0f, 2.0f` into the near plane, far plane arguments, any vertex coordinate in the range 0.0f-2.0f was linearly interpolated into the coordinate system -1.0f to 1.0f to be used as normalized device coordinates. However, no matter which pair of values I put here, nothing is rendered.

Here's the coordinates im trying to draw:

```
rawverts = {
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.7f, 1.0f,
    0.4f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, -0.7f, 1.0f,
    -0.4f, 0.0f, 1.0f
};
```

and when passing the projection matrix to the vertex shader:

```
int projIndex = shaders->uniformLocation("proj");
...
shaders->setUniformValue(projIndex, QMatrix4x4(glm::value_ptr(proj)) );
```

The vertex shader itself:

```
#version 330 core

in vec3 vertex;

uniform mat4 translate;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 proj;

uniform float time;
uniform float aspect;
uniform vec2 resolution;

void main() {
    gl_Position = proj * view * translate * vec4(vertex, 1);
}
```

Comment: 0 is most probably not allowed for the near-plane (at least in all libraries I know). Just for clarification: a perspective projection does NOT perform a linear interpolation.

Comment: "`QMatrix4x4(glm::value_ptr(proj))`" ... what? Have you at least verified that GLM and QT's stuff use the same conventions for their matrix layouts?

Comment: @NicolBolas, Yes, and I stepped through with a debugger to make sure. The other QMatrix objects (translate, view) all work correctly, and the projection matrix has correct looking values in it. I'm still unsure about the impact of the near and far plane values: should all my vertex Z values be between the near and far planes that I set in glm::perspective() to prevent them from being clipped?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **MUST** pass the QMatrix4x4 **transposed** matrix of the glm matrix.

Then instead of using.

```
shaders->setUniformValue(projIndex, QMatrix4x4(glm::value_ptr(proj)) );
```

you must use :

```
shaders->setUniformValue(projIndex, QMatrix4x4(glm::value_ptr(proj)).transposed());
```

Everytime you must send the transposed matrix when you combine QMatrix4x4 and glm::mat4

it should work.

JC

PS : for the record, I also struggle 2 days on this:(